# FATAL:credentials.cc(127) Check failed: . : Permission denied (13) Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Tags: permissions, microsoft-edge, chmod, chown

My OS specifications are given below:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~$ uname -r
5.19.0-1007-nvidia-lowlatency
pegasus@pegasus:~$ uname -a
Linux pegasus 5.19.0-1007-nvidia-lowlatency #7-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 25 00:08:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'd downloaded microsoft-edge-stable[version].deb file using firefox.
and installed it using dpkg -i.
But the app doesn't run using GUI.
When I type microsoft-edge-stable in terminal it gives the following error:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Downloads$ microsoft-edge-stable 
[7399:7399:0503/210255.608214:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

How to get rid of this error and run microsoft edge normally. Again when I use
`microsoft-edge-stable --no-sandbox`
It runs properly

Comment: I searched information and looks like the issue is related to conflicts between root and user permissions. Please refer to [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=258632) to see if it can fix your issue.

Comment: I had checked this already. It's an error that I also faced previously.
Thing is the way they are using chown it's dangerous. 
If I change the permission of /home/user it corrupts the whole OS

Comment: What about removing and reinstalling Edge? If it still doesn't work, you can also ask in [this forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-edge-insider/ct-p/MicrosoftEdgeInsider) to see if you can get more help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?, same symptoms but with vscode. and it opens when using `--no-sandbox` option too. I saw you posted [here](https://www.linux.org/threads/unable-to-launch-any-app-installed-using-dpkg-i.44887/) that you were having this problem with any `.deb` file installed with `dpkg`. But this only started happening after I started messing with many nvidia drivers trying to install cuda (maybe an upgrade? I did one today, I have ubuntu too)

Comment: No couldn't solve it. I'll try the non nvidia kernel as per your suggestion.

Comment: Trouble installing and running a web browser is not a programming issue. This should have been taken to [su] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a new nvidia kernel that gets installed with the (newest?) GPU's nvidia propietary driver, see this other [similar case](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-nvidia-5.19/+bug/2017980).

Changed the kernel on boot up to the *non-nvidia-kernel*, and now Vscode opens normally without having to pass the `--no-sandbox` parameter.

Edge and Vscode both use Chromium under the hood, so any chromium powered app is probably having this issue

Answer (score 6):

One other thing to watch out for is apparmor. Check your dmesg log for something like:

```
[  283.250675] audit: type=1400 audit(1702938463.134:129): apparmor="DENIED" operation="userns_create" class="namespace" info="User namespace creation restricted" error=-13 profile="unconfined" pid=4483 comm="your-app" requested="userns_create" denied="userns_create"
```

If that's the case, try:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0
```

It took me a while to figure this one out, as most answers keep referring to the nvidia modules problems, while this was not the case in my situation.

ref: https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/5462

To make it persist after reboot, add a line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`